# Images not showing up in wordpress localhost

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to make a copy of the live site in the local server. I imported all the files and database. Edited the wp-config and changed the wp_options, wp_posts and wp_metadata table. Still the imgages are not showing up. When I copy the broken image link and paste it on another tab if the brower the image loads but not in the website. Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: I'd suggest using a plugin to make the copy - we've used the [Duplicator plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) for years without issue. It really is the easiest way I've found to do this - you run the plugin (you can change settings if you want but don't need to) to create a zip and installer file. Upload this to the new location, run the installer and you're done. You'll waste more time trying to fix these issues than using this to make a new copy from scratch :)

Comment: @FluffyKitten thanks for your comment, I solved it by using all in one migration plugin.